# Having nested collection but only return facet for the main collection

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I cosmos DB with this kind of documents:

```
{
    "id": "647e50f2-55dc-46ed-9020-13514fb49be2",
    "FirstName": "Natalie",
    "LastName": "Washington",
    "Mobile": "532-6718861",
    "Country": {
        "id": "6d498123-97c6-48fc-afb6-b1c613e4f02b",
        "Name": "Norway"
    },
    "Groups": [
        {
            "id": "2fd2d3e9-61d8-4942-8eb5-3ae58a4ac49e",
            "Name": "Gaming",
            "SubGroupList": [
                {
                    "id": "15063cb9-df87-4fb8-9ecd-a430f1aa7d2e",
                    "Name": "Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cca79f1a-a815-4305-8191-1a43a278e0d4",
                    "Name": "World of Warcraft "
                },
                {
                    "id": "1b412f1d-d82e-4670-a805-10efbd29e6c4",
                    "Name": "Dota 2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e102101a-1613-4c92-9098-9dc0299f11a7",
                    "Name": "Fortnite"
                },
                {
                    "id": "d2862574-5639-4a87-8775-024bc166118c",
                    "Name": "League of Legends"
                },
                {
                    "id": "fc9f0327-f1a1-46c2-b5b3-6ce1667cf5a8",
                    "Name": "Counter-Strike"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "909a9d52-8cdc-43a6-937a-3ef6902ce5c3",
            "Name": "Action Sports",
            "SubGroupList": [
                {
                    "id": "7a56f256-10ec-45cc-b8b3-6cc0539d13c1",
                    "Name": "Kite Surf"
                },
                {
                    "id": "0cde0de0-207b-4129-867b-398fc2040ffd",
                    "Name": "Pakour"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4a89ac41-745b-4e8c-8d75-05d1a43a26da",
                    "Name": "Scooter"
                },
                {
                    "id": "079c07b4-11d4-4281-b3d7-9e0830e96688",
                    "Name": "BMX"
                },
                {
                    "id": "f90eb7d1-1680-4972-8814-15d404326a4a",
                    "Name": "Wakeboard"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1066bbf7-b743-4712-b6bf-fdaf5e11c1c6",
                    "Name": "MTB"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Somehow it is true because the users can be in both sport and gaming. But I only want Groups from gaming because Fortnite is an SubGroup to gaming. So my question is how do I do this kind of hierarchy without having a column for each SubGroups type? Even doing that I am not sure how to connect a Groups column with a sub group column.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to facet by SubGroup, but only include SubGroups belonging to the Group to which Fortnite belongs? Also, have you looked at either of these? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes

Comment: What your describing is what I am trying to do. But by flattening data like the article you link to wont return facets like your describe. But I can see there is a private preview out that hopefully addresses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faceting on only the sub-groups belonging to a particular group is only possible if you model each Group as a separate document. This is because filtering applies at the level of the entire document, whether you use flattening or [Complex Types](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes). So my recommendation would be to index Groups separately for this particular scenario.